# Get output of mongo shell script

Tags: mongodb

as a part of my mongoDB maintenance I'm running mongo shell and make it to load 2 scripts. The command I'm running looks like follows:

> `$MONGO_HOME/bin/mongo --verbose --port 27017 replSetConfig.js initializeReplicaSet.js`

The output I got is:

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.2.3
Thu Mar  7 03:00:00 versionCmpTest passed
Thu Mar  7 03:00:00 versionArrayTest passed connecting to: 127.0.0.1:27017/test
Thu Mar  7 03:00:01 creating new connection to:127.0.0.1:27017
Thu Mar  7 03:00:01 BackgroundJob starting: ConnectBG
Thu Mar  7 03:00:01 connected connection!
loading file: js/replSet.config.js
loading file: js/initializeReplicaSet.js
```

I'm redirecting the output to a log file but I would like to see some output of the loaded scripts as well. I.e. the output which I see in the shell if I start it and call `load("...")` for the very same scripts. Is there a way how to capture the output?

Thanks

Comment: I guess I didnt get the question right. But I use `printjson()` within the mongoscript files for logging.

Comment: It looks like it'll be where I'll end up ... It is suitable for some situations but I don't see how would I log e.g. the rs.intitate() command which I'm calling in the script ... ? This is what I'm calling in the script and I don't see a way how to get the result. I can log rs.status() after the command but in won't tell WHY it failed (if it failed)

Comment: To get the output of a script you must specify print() or printjson() statements otherwise MongoDB will stay silent.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To add output of scripts you must use `print()` or `printjson()` statements otherwise MongoDB will remain quiet about any output of a script.

Comment: Ha, found that you can actually do printjson( rs.initiate(config) ); for example so this is actually what I was looking for.